# Following / Followers persistence bug spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

After referring to other answers on the topic of creating user follows user relation, I made the following user entity-

```
---
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "following",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "following_id"))
  private Set<User> following;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "following", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<User> followers;

---
```

I made a user service to follow other users. this is the implementation. It seems to be saving to the 'following' table, I can see the entry using sql workbench. But when i use another function to get the following set, it is coming as empty. I have no idea how to fix this.

```
    @Override
    public void followUser(Integer user, Integer userToFollow) {

        User firstUser = this.userRepository.findById(user)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User", "Id", user.toString()));

        User secondUser = this.userRepository.findById(userToFollow)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User", "id", userToFollow.toString()));

        Set<User> following = firstUser.getFollowing();
        following.add(secondUser);
        firstUser.setFollowing(following);

        userRepository.save(firstUser);
    }


    @Override
    public List<UserDto> getFollowing(Integer user_id) {
        User user =  this.userRepository.findById(user_id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User", "Id", user_id.toString()));
        Set<User> following = user.getFollowing();

        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<UserDto>>() {}.getType();
        List<UserDto> followersDto = modelMapper.map(following, listType);

        return followersDto;
    }
```

TDLR- Get following returns an empty set even though I can see an entry in the 'following' table on workbench.